# How can I have this deparse function working

Tags: r

I want to be able to use the `deparse` function, if I do this

```
g = function(x) deparse(substitute(x))
```

then it is ok

```
R) g(test)
[1] "test"
```

But if I want to test if the argument of `g` is a `character`

```
h = function(x) {if(is.character(x)){return(x)}; deparse(substitute(x))}
R) h(test)
Error in h(test) : object 'test' not found
```

Why is this happening and I can I fix it ?

EDIT: reproduced from a new `R --vanilla`

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: Are you sure ? have you tried from a clean session ? ohh come on... I'll put my sessionInfo()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in the question is attempting to evaluate a variable, `test`, that does not exist hence the error.  Try this instead:

```
g = function(x) {
    x.try <- try(x, silent = TRUE)
    if (!inherits(x.try, "try-error") && is.character(x.try)) x.try
    else deparse(substitute(x))
}

# test it out
if (exists("test")) rm(test)

g(test) # "test"
g("test") # "test"

test <- "xyz"
g(test) # "xyz"
g("test") # "test"

test <- 3
g(test) # "test"
g("test") # "test"
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `test` doesn't exist in the global environment. `substitute` does not evaluate its argument, so it doesn't look for the object `test`.  `is.character` does evaluate its argument, and therefore throws an error when it can't find `test`.

```
h <- function(x) {if(is.character(x)) x else deparse(substitute(x))}
test <- "hello"
h(test)
```

How you solve your problem depends on what you want the function to do when the object doesn't exist. If you want it to return the object name, then do this:

```
h <- function(x) {
  var <- deparse(substitute(x))
  if(exists(var) && is.character(x)) x else var
}
```