# Dealing with error in functions R(like IFERROR in Excel)

Tags: r

I use `library(optiRum)` to calc PMT and other in R. Have a problem with understanding how can I dealing with ERRORS in FUNCTIONS.

My base example:

```
nper <- c(12,10,10)
pmt <- c(-119.60, -390.94, -148.96)
pv <- c(1144.00, 3909.44, 1489.60)

x<-data.frame(nper, pmt,pv)
```

I create Function like this with tryCatch:

```
RateManual <- function (z,a,b) {
  out <- tryCatch(RATE(z,a,b), error = function(e) 0) 
  return(out)
}
```

Why dont working?

```
RateManual(x$nper, x$pmt, x$pv)
```

Comment: `?try` / `?tryCatch` / `?purrr::safely` / `?purrr::possibly`

Comment: Example please, if you can.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366492/access-matrix-by-rownames-and-colnames-and-return-zero-if-not-available/53366820#53366820 for an example of using `tryCatch` and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811305/how-can-i-have-this-deparse-function-working/15811717#15811717 for an example of using `try`.

Comment: One could ask the same of you @SergeyFido. I see virtually no R code in your question. Just lots of icky Excel function calls.

Comment: nper <- c(12,10,10)
pmt <- c(-119.60, -390.94, -148.96)
pv <- c(1144.00, 3909.44, 1489.60)

x<-data.frame(nper, pmt,pv)

y <- RATE(x$nper, x$pmt, x$pv)